# Django FilteredRelation is not working with GenericRelation

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```py
class Workspace(Model):
    pass

class Event(Model):
    workspace = ForeignKey(Workspace)

    limit = FloatField(default=0)

    entity_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    entity_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    entity = GenericForeignKey('entity_type', 'entity_id')

class Entity(Model):
    events = GenericRelation(Event, content_type_field='entity_type', object_id_field='entity_id')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class SomeEntity(Entity):
    pass
```

Now I need to build a queryset to sort objects of `SomeEntity` by the `limit` of their `events` inside a given `Workspace`

The SQL query I'm hoping to have is something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    "some_entity"."id", workspace_events."id", COALESCE(workspace_events."limit", 0) AS "limit" 
FROM "some_entity" LEFT OUTER JOIN "event" workspace_events
    ON (
        "some_entity"."id" = workspace_events."entity_id" AND 
        workspace_events."entity_type_id" = SOME_ENTITY_CONENT_TYPE_ID AND
        workspace_events."workspace_id" = GIVEN_WORKSPACE_ID
    )
) ORDER BY "limit" DESC'
```

Where:

- `SOME_ENTITY_CONTENT_TYPE_ID` is the content type id of the `SomeEntity` model.
- `GIVEN_WORKSPACE_ID` is the workspace id I want to filter the events on.

The queryset I'm using is this:

```py
SomeEntity.objects.annotate(
    workspace_events=FilteredRelation('events', condition=Q(events__workspace_id=GIVEN_WORKSPACE_ID)),
    limit=Coalesce('workspace_events__limit', 0),
).values('id', 'workspace_events__id', 'limit').order_by('-limit')
```

But the query I'm getting from the above queryset doesn't include the workspace condition in the join at all!

```sql
SELECT 
    "some_entity"."id", workspace_events."id", COALESCE(workspace_events."limit", 0) AS "limit" 
FROM "some_entity" LEFT OUTER JOIN "event" workspace_events
    ON (
        "some_entity"."id" = workspace_events."entity_id" AND 
        workspace_events."entity_type_id" = SOME_ENTITY_CONENT_TYPE_ID AND
    )
) ORDER BY "limit" DESC'
```

What am I doing wrong? Why the workspace condition is not added to the join conditions? And if it's not possible to use `FilteredRelation` with generic relations then how can I produce the SQL query I want using django ORM?